# Simulacrum and trample

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I cast [Simulacrum](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Simulacrum) to retroactively apply damage done to me to a creature I control, but the attacking creatures have trample, does the excess damage get applied to me a second time?

Answer (score 13):

No, trample does not interact with [Simulacrum](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Simulacrum) at all.

First off, make sure you are reading the Oracle wording of the card; that's the actual wording that applies.

> You gain life equal to the damage dealt to you this turn. Simulacrum deals damage to target creature you control equal to the damage dealt to you this turn.

The amount of damage that Simulacrum deals is equal to however much damage you have taken this turn, and that damage is dealt entirely to a single creature you control. Furthermore, it is not combat damage, and trample does not interact in any way with non-combat damage.

Trample only changes how an attacker is allowed to assign combat damage, it allows them to assign less than the total amount to the blocking creature(s) and the rest to the defending player. But it doesn't change the way damage itself is dealt.

Answer (score 0):

With the current Oracle reading, the answer is clearly "no".

> You gain life equal to the damage dealt to you this turn. Simulacrum deals damage to target creature you control equal to the damage dealt to you this turn.

It is Simulacrum that is the source of the damage, not the attacking creature. Simulacrum isn't an attacking creature, it's not assigning combat damage, and it doesn't have trample.

With the original wording, it's not as clear, but if you look at how Trample works, it still wouldn't apply. Trample affects how damage is assigned; Trample means that once the controller of an attacking creature has assigned lethal damage to the blocking creature(s), they can assign the remainder to the defending player. It does *not* mean that if a blocking creature receives more than lethal damage, the excess is applied to the defending player.

For instance, suppose an Abyssal Persecutor (6/6, trample) is blocked by an Alpine Grizzly (4/2). If the attacking player says "Your Alpine Grizzly takes 6 damage", the defending player can say "Okay", and their life total doesn't change; by saying "Your Alpine Grizzly takes 6 damage", the attacking player was assigning all 6 damage to the Alpine Grizzly, leaving none for the defending player. If the attacking player wants to take advantage of Trample, they have to assign 2 damage to Alpine Grizzly and assign 4 to the defending player. Once 6 damage is assigned to Alpine Grizzly, that damage stays on Alpine Grizzly, even though it came from a source with Trample. So if you're that situation as the attacker, if your opponent wants to be really nitpicky they can require you to explicitly state that you're assigning 2 damage to their Alpine Grizzly if you want to assign them any Trample damage.

So in the above hypothetical, if Abysmal Persecutor originally dealt 2 damage to your Alpine Grizzly and 4 damage to you, and then you cast Simulacrum, then even with the original wording, if we interpreted it as saying that the other 4 damage is now being done by Abysmal Persecutor to Alpine Grizzly, and even if we treat this damage as still being Trample combat damage being done by an attacker, that damage still doesn't "overflow" to you; as I said, Trample just gives a permission to assign damage a certain way, it has no effect on damage that has already been assigned.